# How do they perform the giving of a Half shekel in England?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

If the half shekel one gives before Purim needs to be [Male](https://translate.google.com/?hl=en&tab=wT&authuser=0#iw/en/%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%A8%20%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A7%D7%9C) what do they use in England if all the coins have a picture of the Queen? Are there any with Kings or Princes on them?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

In England, the national anthem is "G-d save the Queen". If you spend a half shekel that has The Queen's face on it, how can you "save" the Queen?

There are several ways to circumvent the problem. One way is to give a U.S. dollar (all males on all the bills, for now. That may change pretty soon, BTW!) Or, you can donate the coins after Purim.

If you ask me, I believe the British pound is worth more than U.S. currency. If you really have trouble fulfilling the half shekel mitzvah, you can use for *matanot L'evyonim* by sending your half shekel to a poor American like me :-)